# Extracing IQ samples from a composite signal?

Tags: demodulation

I'm writing a modulator in matlab to simulate IQ data that I would get from my radio to test my demodulator.

I've read that $I = x(t) cos(\omega t)$ and $Q = x(t)  sin(\omega t)$.  What is the $\omega$ term?  If it is $2 \pi f$ then what is the frequency value?

I have a modulated composite signal that I need to split into I and Q parts for my demodulator.  What should be the frequency value in the above equations?

Comment: If you already have a working demodulator or complete specifications (but not the full design) for one, then you should already know what the value of $\omega$ is; it is there in the specs. Your modulator must use the same value of $\omega$ or else the demodulator will not be able to demodulate the output of the modulator.

Comment: Are you trying to extract data samples from a modulated signal (what the title suggests), or modulate data samples (what the question suggests)? At any rate, the posted equations make $I=Q$ (I assume you meant $Q=x(t)\sin(\omega t)$). And yes, I'd expect $\omega=2\pi f$ in that context.

Comment: I'm trying to extract a complex signal form a composite one.  My question is how to determine the frequency to use?